# How to redirect after selecting 2 selections to specific page?­

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wordpress

­I'm doing work on my website and hung up on a code
Please check the below link to understand what i'm trying to say
http://matchpoint.finetiger.com/classes-programs/

Shell RD - Fitness and Training :- example.com
Mill Basin - Fitness and Training :- example2.com

```
<div id="classes-programs-page" class="classes-programs-page text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group find-area">
            <select id="clubs" class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Shell Rd</option>
                <option value="2">Mill Basin</option>
            </select>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group find-area">
            <select id="programs" class="form-control">                
                <option value="3">Fitness & Training </option>
                <option value="4">Aquatics </option>
                <option value="5">Tennis</option>
                <option value="6">Kids Programs</option>
            </select>
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-find">Find</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC BY-SA license). If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)

Comment: This code is private use only and don't want this to use as public. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-find').on('click', check_and_redirect);
  function check_and_redirect() { 
  var urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://www.google.com/", "https://www.yahoo.com/", "https://www.bing.com/", "https://www.wpchandra.com/", "https://www.codexbuddy.com/", "https://www.bbc.com/", "https://nasa.org/"];
  if(($('#programs option:selected').val() != "") && ($("#clubs option:selected").val() != "")){
   if (($("#programs option:selected").length > 0) && ($("#clubs option:selected").length > 0)) {
    var index = parseInt(($('#clubs')[0].selectedIndex) * ($('#programs')[0].selectedIndex))-1;
    window.location = urls[index];
   }
   else{
    alert("Please choose programs and clubs!");
   }
  }
  else{
   alert("Please choose programs and clubs!");
  }
  return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <select id="clubs" class="form-control">
 <option value="">--Select--</option>
 <option value="1">Shell Rd</option>
 <option value="2">Mill Basin</option>
</select>

<select id="programs" class="form-control">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="3">Fitness & Training </option>
  <option value="4">Aquatics </option>
  <option value="5">Tennis</option>
  <option value="6">Kids Programs</option>
 </select>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-find">Find</button>
```

Comment: In this example showing blank because this load under iframe..when you in your website it will be working fine..

Comment: use this code: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        $('#programs').prop('selectedIndex',0);
  $('#clubs').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    }); 
</script>`

Comment: What you need to adding submit button?